# Javascript array gets populated and i don't understand how

Tags: javascript, arrays

While searching a solution for an issue i had about ***Tree Structure from Adjacency List***. i came across an answer that solved it for me but i cannot understand how it's working and i feel like i'm missing some basic understanding about javascript.

The answer by @TreyE in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21343255/1283672) gives the next solution for sorting the tree ->

```js
var flat = [
    { id: 1, name: "Business", parent: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: "Management", parent: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: "Leadership", parent: 2 },
    { id: 4, name: "Finance", parent: 1 },
    { id: 5, name: "Fiction", parent: 0 },
    { id: 6, name: "Accounting", parent: 1 },
    { id: 7, name: "Project Management", parent: 2  }
];

var nodes = [];
var toplevelNodes = [];
var lookupList = {};

for (var i = 0; i < flat.length; i++) {
    var n = {
        id: flat[i].id,
        name: flat[i].name,
        parent_id: ((flat[i].parent == 0) ? null : flat[i].parent),
        children: []
        };
    lookupList[n.id] = n;
    nodes.push(n);
    if (n.parent_id == null) {
        toplevelNodes.push(n);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var n = nodes[i];
  if (!(n.parent_id == null)) {
      lookupList[n.parent_id].children = lookupList[n.parent_id].children.concat([n]);
  }
}

console.log(toplevelNodes);
```

This works just fine but i just cannot understand how all this logic gets ordered under `toplevelNodes` if the only thing that was pushed to it was the first level elements. The rest is done on `nodes` and `lookuplist`. Again i feel like i'm missing some basic understanding of javascript. how does everything sorts into a nice tree of childrens under `topLevelNodes` array ?

Comment: Both `nodes` and `toplevelNodes` are containing the same objects before the last loop is executed. `push` doesn't make a copy of the object, `n` refers to the same object in both arrays.

Comment: I suggest you viewing data with `console.dir(variable)` and trying to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret lies in `lookupList` which is an [**Object**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Items (or *live items*) stored inside that Object are not deep clones, those are just *"pointers"* (not exactly to memory addresses like in C), to existing items in memory, **as reference**. If a node changes (i.e: by adding more children to a Node) that "reference" to that element will be modified as well, since it's actually **that same Node**.

Right in here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var n = nodes[i];
  if (!(n.parent_id == null)) {
      lookupList[n.parent_id].children = lookupList[n.parent_id].children.concat([n]);
  }
}
```

Here's a banally simplified example:

```js
const node_1 = {id: 1, name: "foo", children: []};
const node_2 = {id: 2, name: "bar", children: []};

const lookupList = {};

// store node_1 into lookup - as reference:
lookupList[node_1.id] = node_1;

// (Unrelated to lookupList) add node_2 as child of node_1
node_1.children.push(node_2); 

// Let's sniff lookup for node_1 (id: 1)
console.log(lookupList["1"]); // There's also node_2 as child of node_1

console.log(lookupList["1"] === node_1); // true (it's the same Node)
```

Comment: Tnx @roko, I totally forgot about the pointers and live items things. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

In JS variables that point to object or array hold reference to that object and not a copy of it.

If you have multiple variables pointing to the same object and mutate the object via one variable, the object under the other reference would be mutated as well (because both variables point to the same object):

```js
var a = {hello: 'a'}
var b = a
b.hello = 'b'
console.log(a.hello)
// prints 'b'
```

The same thing happens in your code: `nodes`, `toplevelNodes`, `lookupList` all hold references to the same node objects inside them, when you mutate one in one place, it's also updated in other places.

Basically this is the line that does the magic:

```js
lookupList[n.parent_id].children = ...
```

If you are looking for deeper understanding of this topic, please check this section: https://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#h_C3n45IkMhg

Comment: Wow, finished typing an answer to realise there are already 3 answers available... Perhaps I'm a bit too slow for this Stackoverflow thing...

Answer (score 2):

lookupList maps ids to their nodes, since thats whats added to it in the first loop: `lookupList[n.id] = n`

In the second loop, every node that isn't a top level node is added to its parent's children array. Its parent is retrieved looking up the node's parent_id property in lookupList (`lookupList[n.parent_id]`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another approach would be more easily understood? This will modify `nodes` (née `flat`) in-place, though:

```
/**
  Augment each node in the "nodes" list with a `children` property,
  and return the top-level nodes.
*/
function treeify(nodes) {
  const children = {};

  // Walk through the flat list of nodes once...
  nodes.forEach((n) => {
    // Retrieve or initialize a list for `n.parent`'s children.
    const childList = children[n.parent] || (children[n.parent] = []);
    // Add this node there.
    childList.push(n);
  });

  // ... and walk through it again, to assign the new `children` property.
  nodes.forEach((n) => {
    // Pick each "children" property from the children map,
    // or in case there is none, come up with an empty list.
    n.children = children[n.id] || [];
  });

  // Nodes with parent 0 are top-level; return them.
  return children[0];
}

const nodes = [
  { id: 1, name: "Business", parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "Management", parent: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "Leadership", parent: 2 },
  { id: 4, name: "Finance", parent: 1 },
  { id: 5, name: "Fiction", parent: 0 },
  { id: 6, name: "Accounting", parent: 1 },
  { id: 7, name: "Project Management", parent: 2 },
];

const tree = treeify(nodes);

// Node.js specific printing stuff...
const util = require("util");
console.log(util.inspect(tree, null, { depth: 5 }));
```

This outputs

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Business',
    parent: 0,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Management',
        parent: 1,
        children: [
          { id: 3, name: 'Leadership', parent: 2, children: [] },
          {
            id: 7,
            name: 'Project Management',
            parent: 2,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      },
      { id: 4, name: 'Finance', parent: 1, children: [] },
      { id: 6, name: 'Accounting', parent: 1, children: [] }
    ]
  },
  { id: 5, name: 'Fiction', parent: 0, children: [] }
]
```