# Python - Construct tree structure from table with level numbering

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, tree, hierarchy

I have a table which has been flattened (see **Table 1**, below) to represent a hierarchical tree. I need to create the equivalent nested tree (see **Figure 1**, below).

Is there a general algorithm or concept for doing this?

#### What I've Tried

I'm working in Python 3.11 and subclassing the `anytree` library. However, converting to a nested Python dictionary (in `anytree`'s [expected format](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/importer/dictimporter.html)) would also be a solution.

I have my code shown below in **Listing 1**, but its very rough... all I know is I need to figure out when the `lvl` changes and then add those objects to their parent with recursion.

I've tried processing it recursively but I'm lost on when to recurse, what data to pass, and what my return condition is. See code below in **Listing 1**.

My data is structured similar to an [Adjacency List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342596/tree-structure-from-adjacency-list), but is it similar enough to use code for that?

#### Supporting Data/Info

##### Table 1

| index | lvl | Part # |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 101 |
| 2 | 1 | 101-1 |
| 3 | 2 | 101-1A |
| 4 | 2 | 101-1B |
| 5 | 2 | 101-1C |
| 6 | 2 | 101-1D |
| 7 | 1 | 101-2 |
| 8 | 2 | 101-2A |
| 9 | 2 | 101-2B |
| 10 | 2 | 101-2C |

**Table 1** data is arranged as follows:

- ***index***: A unique row identifier which provides the global order of the entire table.
- ***lvl***: the part's level in the hierachy. E.g. 0 is the root, 1 is the child of the root, etc.
- ***Part #***: The name of the part.

##### Figure 1

[image]

##### Listing 1

```py
"""
Object `TreeNode` is a subclass of `anytree.AnyNode`. The object has 
attributes:
  - `index`: index number (row number)
  - `lvl`: hierarchy level 
  - `parent`: The parent TreeNode of the object.

Parameter `tn_list` is the list of TreeNode objects
Parameter `parent_node` is the root node of the tree. It is a TreeNode object.
Parameter `current_level` keeps up with the current "area" in the tree we are 
           processing. 
           [??] I'm not sure if this will be the parent's level, current 
                node's level, etc.
Parameter `children` is a list of TreeNode objects which are children of 
          `parent_node`.
          [??] I don't think I need this.
"""

def link_TreeNodes(tn_list=None, parent_node=None, children=None, 
                   current_level=None):
    temp_list = []
    children_nodes = []
    
    # Last node's lvl to determine when we need to stop and add all the 
    # children to the parent.
    last_lvl = None
    
    for node in temp_list:
        lvl = getattr(node, 'lvl')
        if last_lvl is None:
            last_lvl = lvl
        else:
            last_lvl = lvl - 1
        
        if lvl == current_level:
            node.parent = parent_node
        elif lvl == current_level + 1:
            children_nodes.append(node)
        elif lvl == current_level - 1:
            # [??] I'm a lost as to what should happen here...
            print(f'current_level: {current_level}; lvl: {lvl}')
        
        # Determine if we need to stop
        if last_lvl == lvl:
            stop = False
            continue
        elif last_lvl == lvl + 1:
            print('Stopping to process children nodes...')
            stop = True
        
        # We have detected a change in the table
        if stop:
            if children_nodes:
                parent_node = link_TreeNodes(
                    tn_list=children_nodes, parent_node=parent_node, 
                    current_level=parent_node.lvl+1)
            else:
                return parent_node
            stop = False
    
    # [??] What is my end condition? What do I return from the recursion?
    return parent_node
```

### Edit 1A: Test data as Python dictionary:

```py
test_data = {'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'level': [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'part_number': ['101', '101-1', '101-1A', '101-1B', '101-1C', '101-1D', '101-2', '101-2A', '101-2B', '101-2C']}
```

### Edit 1B: Output data as nested Python dictionaries:

```py
correct_output = {
    '101': {'parent': None, 'children': ['101-1', '101-2']},
    '101-1': {'parent': '101', 'children': ['101-1A', '101-1B', '101-1C', '101-1D']},
    '101-1A': {'parent': '101-1', 'children': None},
    '101-1B': {'parent': '101-1', 'children': None},
    '101-1C': {'parent': '101-1', 'children': None},
    '101-1D': {'parent': '101-1', 'children': None},
    '101-2': {'parent': '101', 'children': ['101-2A', '101-2B', '101-2C']},
    '101-2A': {'parent': '101-2', 'children': None},
    '101-2B': {'parent': '101-2', 'children': None},
    '101-2C': {'parent': '101-2', 'children': None}
}
```

### Edit 1C: Calling Code

Assume the above input data is in the file `fn` as plain .csv data.

```py
def data_reader(fn):
    data = {}
    with open(fn, newline='') as csvfile:
        creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
        for i, row in enumerate(creader):
            if i == 0:
                continue
            data[int(row[0])] = row[1:]
    return data

def convert2TreeNode(data_dict):
    nodes = []
    for k, v in data_dict.items():
        nodes.append(TreeNode.list2TreeNode(dict_key=k, dict_vals=v))
    return nodes

# if __name__ == '__main__':
nodes = convert2TreeNode(data_reader(fn))
```

Comment: Instead of providing table and figure, can you present the input and desired output in Python syntax (dictionary literal, list, ...etc)? That way there is no ambiguity.

Comment: In your code your first argument is a list of TreeNode objects, which already have a parent attribute. Are we to assume these are all `None`? This question really needs the actual input and call of this function (driver code), so we can reproduce the issue you have with your current solution.

Comment: 1) Edits made for inputs and outputs;    2) At first, yes they would be `None`. I guess my whole objective is to figure out how each TreeNode object is related to the rows above and below it in the .csv data

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using pandas, without recursion and using only the `part_number` column (I assumed that the levels always split at `-` or when followed by an uppercase letter):

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
from pprint import pprint

test_data = {'index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'level': [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'part_number': ['101', '101-1', '101-1A', '101-1B', '101-1C', '101-1D', '101-2', '101-2A', '101-2B', '101-2C']}

df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)[['part_number']]

def find_parent(pn):
    pn_rev = pn[::-1] # no rsplit in re module
    parent_rev = re.split(r'(?<=[A-Z])|-', pn_rev, maxsplit=1)[-1]
    parent = parent_rev[::-1]
    if parent == pn:
        return None
    else:
        return parent

def find_children(x):
    if y:= df.loc[df['parent']==x, 'part_number'].to_list():
        return y
    else:
        return None

df['parent'] = df['part_number'].apply(find_parent)
df['children'] = df['part_number'].apply(find_children)

pprint(df.set_index('part_number').to_dict(orient='index'))
```

Output:

```
{'101': {'children': ['101-1', '101-2'], 'parent': None},
 '101-1': {'children': ['101-1A', '101-1B', '101-1C', '101-1D'], 'parent': '101'},
 '101-1A': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-1'},
 '101-1B': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-1'},
 '101-1C': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-1'},
 '101-1D': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-1'},
 '101-2': {'children': ['101-2A', '101-2B', '101-2C'], 'parent': '101'},
 '101-2A': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-2'},
 '101-2B': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-2'},
 '101-2C': {'children': None, 'parent': '101-2'}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm honestly not sure if the part number will *always* split on the hyphen. I haven't tried your solution yet, but I will get to it soon. This got put on the back burner so I haven't gotten a chance to get back to this!

Comment: I'm finally getting to this. The part number does not always split on the hyphen. Sometimes there is no hyphen. Sometimes the child part number does not even resemble the parent's part number. I think your code is the way forward though. I'll keep working it and get back to accept the answer if it works out. Thanks!!